# Rails (agile web development with rails 4th edition) Problem when loading local website, got the Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am Ruby Rails newbie and I am trying to make a Rails page by Agile guide

When I followed the page, I had this problem. When I tried to open the local host : localhost:3000, it gave me this notification

```
C:/Users/x/Desktop/Ruby on rails/y/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '.' or &. or :: or '[' ...).permit(:\title, :description, :image_url, :price) ... ^
```

My line 72 in file `products_controller.rb` is

```
params.require(:product).permit(:\title, :description, :image_url, :price)
```

My log is

```
SyntaxError (C:/Users/y/Desktop/Ruby on rails/y/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
...ams.require(:product).permit(:\title, :description, :image_u...
...                              ^
C:/Users/y/Desktop/Ruby on rails/y/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '.' or &. or :: or '['
...).permit(:\title, :description, :image_url, :price)
...                              ^):
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '.' or &. or :: or '['
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '.' or &. or :: or '['
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '.' or &. or :: or '['
```

I am a newbie, and very confuse with this problem. Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Remove the "\" in `\title`. Try again.

Comment: @Sebastian Palma: thank you for your comment, but after removing the "\" in the `\title` and tried to load the server, they even can not load the server and gave me the message `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`  Do you have another idea for me ?

Comment: See the logs. Copy and paste them in your question.

Comment: Here is my logs `app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '.' or &. or :: or '['`, they said that they have unexpected backslash, but when I removed the unexpected backslash, I could not load the server, sould I remove all the `title` ?

Comment: Add the whole stacktrace of the error, as it is. Don't worry if it's too long. Add it to your question by updating it, not in comments.

Comment: Dear Sebastian Palma, I have just update all the stacktrace as it is, could you please give me some ideas ?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you removed the backslash in the line 72. You still have the same problem `.permit(:\title, :description, :image_url, :price)`.

Comment: Try restarting your server. `CTRL-C` `rails s`

Comment: If you get another something went wrong error then post the new log file entries showing the new error

Answer (score -1):

```
params.require(:product).permit(:\title, :description, :image_url, :price)
```

should be

```
params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price)
```

Comment: Dear friends, I solved my problem. It was not just remove the \ in that line but it was because when I made all that code by this code, bin/rails generate scaffold Product \title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal, I had the \ before the title and it was the cause. Thank you for all your comment.